# Fixed effects model: Error in chol.default(mat[ok, ok]) : the leading minor of order # is not positive definite

Tags: r, error-handling

While trying to estimate this model:

```
# Dynamic model R&D intensity 3 years post merger incl covariates pre3
m10b <- felm(RD_intensity ~ merger_it + merger_it_post1 + merger_it_post2 + merger_it_post3 + factor(year) + RDint_pre3 + profit_pre3 + employees_pre3
           | company | 0 | company,
           data = TandC,
           subset = RD_intensity > pcts2[1] & RD_intensity < pcts2[2])
summary(m10b)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in chol.default(mat[ok, ok]) : the leading minor of order 14 is not positive definite
```

Since I'm quite new in R, I have no idea what to do with this.
Does anyone have an idea what this error means? Does it have anything to do with a too-small sample or multicollinearity? Or simply a coding mistake?

Help is very much appreciated!

These are the first 30 rows of my sample:

```
structure(list(company = c("ALLERGAN PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY", 
"ALLERGAN PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY", "ALLERGAN PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY", 
"ALLERGAN PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY", "ALLERGAN PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY", 
"ALLERGAN PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY", "ALLERGAN PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY", 
"ALPINE ELECTRONICS, INC.", "ALPINE ELECTRONICS, INC.", "ALPINE ELECTRONICS, INC.", 
"ALPINE ELECTRONICS, INC.", "ALPINE ELECTRONICS, INC.", "ALPINE ELECTRONICS, INC.", 
"ALPS ALPINE CO.,LTD.", "ALPS ALPINE CO.,LTD.", "ALPS ALPINE CO.,LTD.", 
"ALPS ALPINE CO.,LTD.", "ALPS ALPINE CO.,LTD.", "ALPS ALPINE CO.,LTD.", 
"ANICURA STOCKHOLMS REGIONDJURSJUKHUS AB", "ANICURA STOCKHOLMS REGIONDJURSJUKHUS AB", 
"ANICURA STOCKHOLMS REGIONDJURSJUKHUS AB", "ANICURA STOCKHOLMS REGIONDJURSJUKHUS AB", 
"ANICURA STOCKHOLMS REGIONDJURSJUKHUS AB", "ANICURA STOCKHOLMS REGIONDJURSJUKHUS AB", 
"APOGEE ENTERPRISES INC", "APOGEE ENTERPRISES INC", "APOGEE ENTERPRISES INC", 
"APOGEE ENTERPRISES INC", "APOGEE ENTERPRISES INC"), year = c(2013L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2019L), case_code = c("M.8193", "M.8193", "M.8193", "M.8193", 
"M.8193", "M.8193", "M.8193", "M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", 
"M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", 
"M.8833", "M.9019", "M.9019", "M.9019", "M.9019", "M.9019", "M.9019", 
"M.9060", "M.9060", "M.9060", "M.9060", "M.9060"), merger = c(2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), acquirer = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), country = c("IE", "IE", "IE", "IE", 
"IE", "IE", "IE", "JP", "JP", "JP", "JP", "JP", "JP", "JP", "JP", 
"JP", "JP", "JP", "JP", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "US", 
"US", "US", "US", "US"), industry_firm = c(2120, 2120, 2120, 
2120, 2120, 2120, 2120, 6420, 6420, 6420, 6420, 6420, 6420, 2611, 
2611, 2611, 2611, 2611, 2611, 7500, 7500, 7500, 7500, 7500, 7500, 
2314, 2314, 2314, 2314, 2314), industry_firm_2 = c(21, 21, 21, 
21, 21, 21, 21, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23), industry_merger = c(4646, 
4646, 4646, 4646, 4646, 4646, 4646, 453, 453, 453, 453, 453, 
453, 453, 453, 453, 453, 453, 453, 1092, 1092, 1092, 1092, 1092, 
1092, 262, 262, 262, 262, 262), industry_merger_2 = c(46, 46, 
46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 
45, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26), simpl_proc = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), commitments = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), cross_border = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), duration = c(25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 149, 149, 
149, 149, 149, 149, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35), employees = c(384, 432, 
624, 334, 356, 338, 348, 1122, 1110, 1492, 1317, NA, NA, 39588, 
42053, 42289, 41840, 40443, NA, 285, 372, 279, 367, 427, NA, 
4614, 5511, 6700, 7000, 7200), profit_margin = c(-0.14684, -0.85298, 
-0.58792, -0.38872, -1.30312, -0.86866, -0.6363, -1.925, 0.567, 
3.984, 4.01, NA, NA, 8.763, 6.572, 7.599, 4.838, 1.921, NA, 8.049, 
6.641, 8.856, 7.592, 3.538, NA, 9.919, 11.019, 8.285, 4.182, 
5.748), RD_expenses = c(8946.414554, 9977.75638, 43326.90616, 
48870.14658, 35022.10866, 39584.25952, 32259.2173, 6303.95, 6812.46, 
14993.39, 21925.5, NA, NA, 259971.9513, 269457.2012, 227757.0765, 
263893.2745, 316285.6753, NA, 7053.5, 1722.05, 2131.71, NA, NA, 
NA, 7347.538084, 8115.501556, 11462.26181, 17081.29815, 15122.53385
), sales = c(125844.3945, 111010.5704, 276862.329, 276455.8596, 
265833.4972, 275762.3064, 286432.2966, 1260609.732, 1217111.106, 
1094409.478, 2057945, NA, NA, 6036362.168, 6288047.037, 6560212.444, 
6831502.438, 6806267.552, NA, 27113.77546, 29621.68519, 31647.16693, 
33653.0387, 35262.84214, NA, 901165.4432, 1051743.523, 1085781.581, 
1228659.528, 1263951.4), period = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("-3", "-2", 
"-1", "0", "1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), merger_it = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), merger_it_pre1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0), merger_it_post3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), merger_it_post2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), merger_it_post1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1), RD_intensity = c(7.10910850621956, 8.98811378416267, 
15.6492601635234, 17.6773777378817, 13.1744528168514, 14.3544852219875, 
11.2624231565094, 0.500071500320608, 0.559723756230354, 1.36999818636439, 
1.06540748173542, NA, NA, 4.30676530109749, 4.28522877794115, 
3.47179422075435, 3.86288780389073, 4.6469768178164, NA, 26.0144516222235, 
5.8134774877067, 6.73586360736525, NA, NA, NA, 0.815337310084728, 
0.771623630526508, 1.05566920737809, 1.39023852912326, 1.19644899716872
), age = c(36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 
73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72), industry = c(46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 45, 45, 45, 45, 
45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 26, 26, 
26, 26, 26), treated = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), id = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), RDexp_pre1 = c(NA, 
8946.414554, 9977.75638, 43326.90616, 48870.14658, 35022.10866, 
39584.25952, NA, 6303.95, 6812.46, 14993.39, 21925.5, NA, NA, 
259971.9513, 269457.2012, 227757.0765, 263893.2745, 316285.6753, 
NA, 7053.5, 1722.05, 2131.71, NA, NA, NA, 7347.538084, 8115.501556, 
11462.26181, 17081.29815), profit_pre1 = c(NA, -0.14684, -0.85298, 
-0.58792, -0.38872, -1.30312, -0.86866, NA, -1.925, 0.567, 3.984, 
4.01, NA, NA, 8.763, 6.572, 7.599, 4.838, 1.921, NA, 8.049, 6.641, 
8.856, 7.592, 3.538, NA, 9.919, 11.019, 8.285, 4.182), RDint_pre1 = c(NA, 
7.10910850621956, 8.98811378416267, 15.6492601635234, 17.6773777378817, 
13.1744528168514, 14.3544852219875, NA, 0.500071500320608, 0.559723756230354, 
1.36999818636439, 1.06540748173542, NA, NA, 4.30676530109749, 
4.28522877794115, 3.47179422075435, 3.86288780389073, 4.6469768178164, 
NA, 26.0144516222235, 5.8134774877067, 6.73586360736525, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.815337310084728, 0.771623630526508, 1.05566920737809, 
1.39023852912326), employees_pre1 = c(NA, 384, 432, 624, 334, 
356, 338, NA, 1122, 1110, 1492, 1317, NA, NA, 39588, 42053, 42289, 
41840, 40443, NA, 285, 372, 279, 367, 427, NA, 4614, 5511, 6700, 
7000), RDexp_pre2 = c(NA, NA, 8946.414554, 9977.75638, 43326.90616, 
48870.14658, 35022.10866, NA, NA, 6303.95, 6812.46, 14993.39, 
21925.5, NA, NA, 259971.9513, 269457.2012, 227757.0765, 263893.2745, 
NA, NA, 7053.5, 1722.05, 2131.71, NA, NA, NA, 7347.538084, 8115.501556, 
11462.26181), profit_pre2 = c(NA, NA, -0.14684, -0.85298, -0.58792, 
-0.38872, -1.30312, NA, NA, -1.925, 0.567, 3.984, 4.01, NA, NA, 
8.763, 6.572, 7.599, 4.838, NA, NA, 8.049, 6.641, 8.856, 7.592, 
NA, NA, 9.919, 11.019, 8.285), employees_pre2 = c(NA, NA, 384, 
432, 624, 334, 356, NA, NA, 1122, 1110, 1492, 1317, NA, NA, 39588, 
42053, 42289, 41840, NA, NA, 285, 372, 279, 367, NA, NA, 4614, 
5511, 6700), RDexp_pre3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 8946.414554, 9977.75638, 
43326.90616, 48870.14658, NA, NA, NA, 6303.95, 6812.46, 14993.39, 
NA, NA, NA, 259971.9513, 269457.2012, 227757.0765, NA, NA, NA, 
7053.5, 1722.05, 2131.71, NA, NA, NA, 7347.538084, 8115.501556
), profit_pre3 = c(NA, NA, NA, -0.14684, -0.85298, -0.58792, 
-0.38872, NA, NA, NA, -1.925, 0.567, 3.984, NA, NA, NA, 8.763, 
6.572, 7.599, NA, NA, NA, 8.049, 6.641, 8.856, NA, NA, NA, 9.919, 
11.019), employees_pre3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 384, 432, 624, 334, NA, 
NA, NA, 1122, 1110, 1492, NA, NA, NA, 39588, 42053, 42289, NA, 
NA, NA, 285, 372, 279, NA, NA, NA, 4614, 5511), RDint_pre2 = c(NA, 
NA, 7.10910850621956, 8.98811378416267, 15.6492601635234, 17.6773777378817, 
13.1744528168514, NA, NA, 0.500071500320608, 0.559723756230354, 
1.36999818636439, 1.06540748173542, NA, NA, 4.30676530109749, 
4.28522877794115, 3.47179422075435, 3.86288780389073, NA, NA, 
26.0144516222235, 5.8134774877067, 6.73586360736525, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.815337310084728, 0.771623630526508, 1.05566920737809), 
    RDint_pre3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 384, 432, 624, 334, NA, NA, NA, 
    1122, 1110, 1492, NA, NA, NA, 39588, 42053, 42289, NA, NA, 
    NA, 285, 372, 279, NA, NA, NA, 4614, 5511)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000231e7fc1ef0>)
```

Comment: yes, probably collinearity. Can you use `model.matrix` + `caret::findLinearCombos` to check ?

Comment: I will! What package do I need to install to run this?

Comment: `model.matrix` is in base R, `caret` is the name of the package for `findLinearCombos` (that's what the `::` syntax means)

Comment: Thanks! It seems not to work however, I get this error: Error in enumLC.default(x) : enumLC does not support felm objects

Comment: yes; you need to create a model matrix *or* a more-or-less equivalent `lm()` fit in order to check. (Presumably `felm` also creates an internal model matrix, but I don't know what the steps would be.) It would be easier with a [mcve], although those are hard for large data sets ...